# YII2 how to insert data from select table with table on another database

Tags: yii2

Hi Guys i have two connection database and query bellow

```
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;
$connection2 = \Yii::$app->db2;

$insert = $connection->createCommand('INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3) 
       select field1,field2,field3 from table2');
$insert->execute();
```

Ask, how to table2 to connect $connection2 ?.. because table2 on another database. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in yii, it's even not possible in SQL if 2 different servers are used (e.g. not linked). 
In SQL server it's possible to link remote database or add it to synonym, but I don't think you need such complex solution.

If databases are on same server it can be achieved with query like:

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1 (field1, field2, field3) 
       SELECT field1,field2,field3 from db2.table2
```

Otherwise get data from `db2`, form inserts and insert to `db1`